# Take automated desktop screenshots on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, script, screenshot

What I am visualizing is a script that takes desktops screenshots every 10-20 minutes and stores them in a protected folder. Non-admin users should not be able to disable the script or access the folder. We use N-Computing, so 5 users are logged in at any time.

Answer (score 1):

I would think a Mix of these should get you good:

[Powershell Screen Capture Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969321/how-can-i-do-a-screen-capture-in-windows-powershell)

[Task Scheduler powershell](http://whileloop.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/running-powershell-scripts-as-scheduled-task-like-cronjobs-for-windows/)

and lastly you could create a folder with Admin Write permissions and READ for whoever. Just make sure the script is scheduled by admin and you should be good to go.

good luck!